# Find All TD's w/ attribute in Specific Table (by ID)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, kendo-ui

I'm using Telerik's Kendo suite and I need to perform a check on each cell in the Scheduler widget.  I do this by searching for an attribute called 'role' and doing an .each on them.  This works fine, but if I have multiple schedulers on the page I don't want to iterate over all td's...just ones in a specific scheduler (which is an html table under the hood).
I tried giving the scheduler an ID, but the selector doesn't seem to find any td's.
When I just use ("td[role=gridcell]").each it works but comes back with all td's in the page.  If I try adding the id of the scheduler I want, it comes back with nothing.

```
var scheduler = $("#scheduler").data("kendoScheduler");
var view = scheduler.view();
view.table.find("#scheduler td[role=gridcell]").each(function (index, value)
{
    // Do checking here.
})
```

I'm sure there's an issue with my syntax in the selector but I can't figure it out.

Comment: If you want help from people that aren't intimately familiar with the Scheduler control, then you will need to show the relevant HTML that you are trying to find TDs in, including examples of TDs you want to find and TDs you don't want to find.

Comment: Maybe I provided too much information.  I believe the fact that I'm working with Kendo is irrelevant.  My question is really "How do I find all TD's with a specific attribute value inside a table with an ID of 'scheduler'?"

Comment: You just didn't provide to minimum necessary information to understand what you were trying to solve.  A simple table HTML example showing what cells you wanted to find without any of the other information would have gotten you an answer within a few minutes.

Comment: I'll keep that in mind for the future.  Still pretty new to SO.  Thanks again!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no need for the `#scheduler` selector in the `find` call.

```js
$("#scheduler").find("td[role=gridcell]").each(function (index, value) {
  $(value).css('color', 'red');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<table id="scheduler">
    <tr>
        <td role="gridcell">A</td>
        <td role="gridcell">B</td>
        <td>C</td>
        <td>D</td>
    </tr>
</table>

<table id="test">
    <tr>
        <td role="gridcell">A</td>
        <td role="gridcell">B</td>
        <td>C</td>
        <td>D</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: You are absolutely right, was just getting ready to post the same.  In my case, there was no need to specify the id because I was already looking at the scheduler due to the 'view' variable referencing the scheduler in question.  Thanks!

Comment: No need for the separate `.find()`.  It can all just be put into the selector.

Comment: @jfriend00 Sure, but in the question he was using `find`, and the `find` selector was seemingly the problem, so I illustrated that.

Answer (score 0):

In jQuery, you should just be able to do this:

```
$("#scheduler td[role='gridcell']").each(function(index, elem) {
    // code here
});
```

Note: There is no need to use a separate `.find()` operation as you can just put it all into the selector.

See demo: http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/49Lg411h/